# removeClass not being applied

Tags: jquery, lightbox, colorbox

On below I am opening thumb in preview above and then have image opening in a colorbox.

```
$('.picthumb').on('click', function(event){
    var $pic = $(this).find('img');
    $('.piclg').attr('src',$pic.attr('src'));
    $('.picthumb .selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(".picthumb").removeClass('cboxElement');
});

<div class="piclg"></div>
<div class="picthumb"></div>
```

Picthumb is a row of thumbnails which I am trying to remove the cboxelement with no success. Currently clicking on thumb opens modal. As well clicking on piclg opens modal. If I disable Colorbox thumb opens the piclg fine. Goal is to click thumb, open in piclg and then in larger Colorbox modal on click.

Hope the above makes sense. Would appreciate pointers to sort this. Thanks.

[image: Gallery images]

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. With Delegate binding of dynamic elements, like with `.on()`,  your initial selector should be the closest parent that is a static element. You will then delegate the click event to the dynamic element via a selector. See more: https://api.jquery.com/on/ If you want more help, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @twisty thanks for the pointers. I will do some reading up and see if I get anywhere.